# regex for changing array() to [] using atom

Tags: php, arrays, atom-editor

I am wanting to update my php script as a project (globally) and change array(elements); to [elements];

Using atom i have already ran the update for just the init of arrays and have already changed array(); to [];  however this just takes care of the empty array initialization codes.

The challenge now is to change arrays that actually have elements in them from () to []

For example the arrays could be in several formats

```
array('content',number content,'content');
```

or

```
array(
      'content',
                array(
                      number content,'content'
                      )
      );
```

or any variation of the number of levels.

I have broken it down this way but i dont know how to do the regex.,

Find every occurance of array(
-  replace with [

Find the associated close of that array );
-replace with ];

Find every array( inside another which is  array(
-replace with [

Find the associated close of each of those arrays that are inside another array  ); or just ),
- replace with ]; or ],

I think that should cover it.... is the regex going to be impossible to do?

thanks

Comment: This will be a challenge, to say the least. Atom and other modern editors have built in language-specific intellisense functionalities that might come in useful here, but doing it with Regexp alone will be either very hard to do or error-prone.

Comment: You could try repeatedly applying the following Regexp: `array\(([^()]*)\)`, with the replacement string: `array[$1]`.It will work from the inside to the outside. But only if there aren't any `(` or `)` inside any of the strings of your array-elements.

Comment: Well my feeling is that even if there are a few bugs caused, its easier to fix those individually when found than it is to change all these manually one by one.  At least regex could do most of the work and then we would need to make corrections after that.

Comment: According to regex101 site that will match array(1,'goat') and just the inside array of this one array('happy',36,
                array('sad',25)
      );    and then once the inside is changed then you run it again and it changes the outside... this may work just fine...

Comment: However first bug... it also matches is_array($value) and other array functions such as in_array also which is not good, how can i exclude the function, shoud i exclude anything with _ preceding array or just anything at all preceding array

Comment: ok so this seems to work [^_]array\(([^()]*)\)  to exclude functions, it excludes preceding _

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing, that you are willing to do some manual repairs afterwards and that the solution suggested in my comment is of interest to you I now put it in "proper" answer form. This is easier to edit and to discuss. As said before, this is only a "workaround", as we are not really parsing the text in the sense of really *understanding* it syntactically. However, when you apply the following Regexp

```
\barray\(([^()]*)\)
```

repeatedly and replace it with

```
[$1]
```

(yes, I left out the "array" in front of "["!) you might have a chance of doing what you want.

I put a `\b` in front of the Regexp to make it look for a word boundary. This way we exclude text fragments like `is_array()` or `myarray()` from being changed.

Comment: I am such a idiot, its not array[] its just [] and ill have to start over because i didnt catch that mistake.   $array = array() gets modified to $array = []   so sad i goofed up... So do we need to redo the regex to change array() to [] ?   i am so sorry...

Comment: I did change the original request to the correct syntax